# Add column to each data frame within list with function rowSums and range of columns

Tags: r, dataframe

SO. The following might serve as a small example of the real list.

```
a <- data.frame(
  x = c("A","A","A","A","A"),
  y = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  z = c(1,2,3,4,5))

b <- data.frame(
  x = c("A","A","A","A","A"),
  y = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  z = c(1,2,3,4,5))

c <- data.frame(
  x = c("A","A","A","A","A"),
  y = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  z = c(1,2,3,4,5))

l <- list(a,b,c)
```

From the second column to last column - on every data frame - i want to add the sums as a new column to each data frame.

I tried:

```
lapply(l, function(x) rowSums(x[2:ncol(x)]))
```

which returns the correct sums, but doesn't add them to the data frames.

I also tried:

```
lapply(l, transform, sum = y + z)
```

which gives me the correct results but is not flexible enough, because i don't always know how many columns there are for each data frame and what names they have. The only thing i know, is, that i have to start from second column to end. I tried to combine these two approaches but i can't figure out, how to do it exactly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to combine your attempts. I used `data[-1]` instead of `data[2:ncol(data)]` because it seems simpler, but either should work.

```
lapply(l, function(data) transform(data, sum = rowSums(data[-1])))
```

Unfortunately, `transform` will be confused if the name of the argument to your anonymous function is the same as a column name - `data[-1]` needs to look at the data frame, not a particular column. (I originally use `function(x)` instead of `function(data)`, and this caused an error because there is a column named `x`. From this perspective, Duck's answer is a little safer.)

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I am getting an error, that x must be numeric. My columns are integers but i thought that might work too. Now i first have to check how to turn them all numeric to try again with your code.

Comment: Integers are numerics - double check that *all* your non-first columns are numeric (including integers). Try `lapply(l, function(x) {x[-1]; x[!is.numeric(x)]})` to see any non-numeric columns.

Comment: They are integers. All of them. the difference with the original data frame is that instead of starting at column 2 i want to start at column 3. Do i just have to fix data[-1] to data[-2]?

Comment: fixed it with data[3:ncol(data)] instead of data[-1]. Thanks!

Comment: Alternately `data[-(1:2)]` to drop 1st and 2nd column. Or `Filter(is.numeric, data)` for all numeric columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can play around index in columns and exclude the first variable so that there is not issues about how many additional variables you have in order to obtain the rowsums. Here the code:

```
#Compute rowsums
l1 <- lapply(l,function(x) {x$RowSum<-rowSums(x[,-1],na.rm=T);return(x)})
```

Output:

```
l1
[[1]]
  x y z RowSum
1 A 1 1      2
2 A 2 2      4
3 A 3 3      6
4 A 4 4      8
5 A 5 5     10

[[2]]
  x y z RowSum
1 A 1 1      2
2 A 2 2      4
3 A 3 3      6
4 A 4 4      8
5 A 5 5     10

[[3]]
  x y z RowSum
1 A 1 1      2
2 A 2 2      4
3 A 3 3      6
4 A 4 4      8
5 A 5 5     10
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> add_col <- function(df){
+                         df[(ncol(df)+1)] = rowSums(df[2:ncol(df)])
+                         df
+                       }
> lapply(l, add_col)  
[[1]]
  x y z V4
1 A 1 1  2
2 A 2 2  4
3 A 3 3  6
4 A 4 4  8
5 A 5 5 10

[[2]]
  x y z V4
1 A 1 1  2
2 A 2 2  4
3 A 3 3  6
4 A 4 4  8
5 A 5 5 10

[[3]]
  x y z V4
1 A 1 1  2
2 A 2 2  4
3 A 3 3  6
4 A 4 4  8
5 A 5 5 10

>
```

With sum as column name:

```
> add_col <- function(df){
+                         df['sum'] = rowSums(df[2:ncol(df)])
+                         df
+                       }
> lapply(l, add_col)  
[[1]]
  x y z sum
1 A 1 1   2
2 A 2 2   4
3 A 3 3   6
4 A 4 4   8
5 A 5 5  10

[[2]]
  x y z sum
1 A 1 1   2
2 A 2 2   4
3 A 3 3   6
4 A 4 4   8
5 A 5 5  10

[[3]]
  x y z sum
1 A 1 1   2
2 A 2 2   4
3 A 3 3   6
4 A 4 4   8
5 A 5 5  10
```

Comment: This is the only one working on my original data frame. The only thing is, that i am getting a funny name for the columns (...7).

Comment: yes, you may assign names later on using names() function.

Comment: Or you can use lapply(l, function(x) setNames(x, c('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'))) for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yours would work, too, but i prefer another approach where i have the correct name.

Comment: Have modified the code a bit to suit your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

use `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)
map(l, ~.x %>% mutate(Sum := apply(.x[-1], 1, sum)))

#> [[1]]
#>   x y z Sum
#> 1 A 1 1   2
#> 2 A 2 2   4
#> 3 A 3 3   6
#> 4 A 4 4   8
#> 5 A 5 5  10
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   x y z Sum
#> 1 A 1 1   2
#> 2 A 2 2   4
#> 3 A 3 3   6
#> 4 A 4 4   8
#> 5 A 5 5  10
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   x y z Sum
#> 1 A 1 1   2
#> 2 A 2 2   4
#> 3 A 3 3   6
#> 4 A 4 4   8
#> 5 A 5 5  10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map` with `mutate`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(l, ~ .x %>%
            mutate(sum = rowSums(select(., -1))))
```

Or with `c_across`

```
map(l, ~ .x %>%
           rowwise() %>%
           mutate(sum = sum(c_across(-1), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
           ungroup)
```